# How to write an apply() function to limit each element in a matrix column to a maximum allowable value?

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to learn how to use the `apply()` functions.

Suppose we have a 3 row, 2 column matrix of `test <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), ncol = 2)`, and we would like the maximum value of each element in the first column (1, 2, 3) to not exceed 2 for example, so we end up with a matrix of (1,2,2,4,5,6).

How would one write an `apply()` function to do this?

Here's my latest attempt: `test1 <-  apply(test[,1], 2, function(x) {if(x > 2){return(x = 2)} else {return(x)}})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We may use `pmin` on the first column with value 2 as the second argument, so that it does elementwise checking with the recycled 2 and gets the minimum for each value from the first column

```
test[,1] <- pmin(test[,1], 2)
```

-output

```
> test
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    2    6
```

---

Note that `apply` needs the 'X' as an array/matrix or one with `dim`ensions, when we subset only a single column/row, it drops the dimensions because `drop = TRUE` by default

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use the `apply()` function, I guess you're looking for something like this:

```
t(apply(test, 1, function(x) c(min(x[1], 2), x[2])))
##       [,1] [,2]
##  [1,]    1    4
##  [2,]    2    5
##  [3,]    2    6
```

But if you want my opinion, akrun's suggestion is definitely better.

Comment: Agreed, akrun's solution is efficient and elegant. However, I am working on my apply() family skills as all those related functions (lapply, sapply, mapply) are critical to my overall project, so thank you for your response and I'm studying it now.

Comment: Quick question: why is it necessary to transpose the original matrix?

Comment: You don’t have to! I just wanted to make sure you had the dimensions in the output than the input.